# electron puppeteer js cannot statically analyse

Tags: webpack, electron, puppeteer

Asked on SO related to vue, nextJs, angular but unrelated to Electron.
Also asked [here](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/issues/597) on git issues related to puppeteer-extra - electron but the answer deviated and it went into Next JS.  Here is [another one](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/issues/507) asked for Vue/Electron.

Node 16
Mac
When running `yarn add puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth`
The error I get is:

ERROR in ./node_modules/merge-deep/node_modules/clone-deep/utils.js 11:0-38
Cannot statically analyse 'require(…, …)' in line 11
@ ./node_modules/merge-deep/node_modules/clone-deep/index.js 7:12-30
@ ./node_modules/merge-deep/index.js 11:12-33
@ ./node_modules/puppeteer-extra-plugin/dist/index.esm.js 9:14-35
@ ./node_modules/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth/index.js 3:33-66
@ dll renderer renderer[12]

Any idea how to resolve this?